# Windows 8 "Insufficient memory" error whilst copying through .bat files

Tags: windows, windows-8, google-chrome, memory, batch-file

**Info:**
**Sys:** Windows 8 Pro 64-bit (6.2, Build 9200) (9200.win8_gdr.130531-1504)
**BIOS:** Default System BIOS
**Processor:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU ; 960  @ 3.20GHz (8 CPUs), ~3.2GHz
**Memory:** 14336MB RAM  (14GB)
**Available OS Memory:** 14328MB RAM
**Page File:** 6949MB used, 21713MB available
**Windows Dir:** C:\Windows
**DirectX Version:** DirectX 11
**Special Info:** I have my Chrome Profiles on my E: Drive linked through a junction.

**Process causing error**
I run a master .bat which is my *command centre* which runs copies of my chrome user data and then zips it, copies it to my Dropbox & backup folders.  I run it to copy only certain profiles (work / client etc) and to do one copy of all, but not keep a synced copy, it goes nowhere as it's big.

This is the bat file

```
:: Set variable for date in format yymmdd  
set Date=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~7,2%%DATE:~4,2%  
set Year=%date:~0,4%  
SET Month=%DATE:~4,2%  
if %Month%==01 set Month=JAN  
if %Month%==02 set Month=FEB  
if %Month%==03 set Month=MAR  
if %Month%==04 set Month=APR  
if %Month%==05 set Month=MAY  
if %Month%==06 set Month=JUN  
if %Month%==07 set Month=JUL  
if %Month%==08 set Month=AUG  
if %Month%==09 set Month=SEP  
if %Month%==10 set Month=OCT  
if %Month%==11 set Month=NOV  
if %Month%==12 set Month=DEC  
echo %Month%  
set Day=%Date:~6,2%  

@echo off  
color   0A  
echo Command Centre Chrome  
echo.  

color 0F  
echo Killing Chrome  
Call "chromekill.bat"  

timeout /t 15

color 0B
echo Running CCleaner
Call "ccleaner auto.bat"

timeout /t 75
pause

color 0C
echo Running Chrome Backup
call "chrome folder.bat"

timeout /t 30

color 0D
echo Running Chrome zip
call "chrome zip.bat"

timeout /t 30

color 0E
echo Running Zip Copies
call "chrome zip copy.bat"

pause
```

**Error** 
Insuffcient memory
xxx Files(s) copied
(Could be 800, 4000, 12000 any number)

I have followed the instructions here:  http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/vista-hands-on-17-solving-a-pesky-resource-problem/269
I increased it to: Windows SharedSection=1024,40960,768

I looked at this:  [Creating .xz with 7-Zip, claims insufficient memory (not true)](https://superuser.com/questions/264909/creating-xz-with-7-zip-claims-insufficient-memory-not-true)
And it's over 2yrs old and on another OS.  (I am aware that some Win fixes carry over, but, I'm not even sure on the terms that are being used.)

My file folders are:
Profile 1:  194MB; 3,566 files & 1,110 Folders
Profile 2:  87.2MB; 2,227 files & 893 Folders
Profile 3:  214MB; 4,114 files & 978 Folders
Profile 12: 41.3MB; 822 files & 459 Folders

Largest copy is the whole history:

```
color 0C  
echo Running Chrome Backup  
xcopy "C:\Users\----\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome" "G:\My Boxes\1 all Shared\1 Backups\2 Programs\2 Google\Chrome\%date% - %Year% %Month% %Day%\Chrome All Profiles %date%" /e /v /y /i
```

==> 936MB; 30,169 Files & 9,774 Folders

I have removed the "All" and run the .bat and it still runs an error.  Compressing the folders & files that do copy over are not throwing the errors, it seems to be only the copying over.

Thank you in advance.